latexmk plus error handling
I would like to work with latexmk in continuous mode,
    (setq TeX-command-default "Latexmk")
    (push '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -pvc -synctex=1 %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
                :help "Run latexmk on file")
                 TeX-command-list)

PLUS reasonable error handling as in AUCTeX; that is, display the error message and jump to the error within the text buffer.
How can this be accomplished?

AuCTeX have add support for latexmk, you don't need to add it to TeX-command-list anymore.
see https://github.com/emacsmirror/auctex/blob/d298219d0f335faa1094a8606018460225b2cd1f/NEWS.org#added-3

Does this mean it is enough to (setq TeX-command-default "LaTeXMk")?

You need (setq-default TeX-command-default "LaTeXmk") or (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "LaTeXmk")))
